# Using Oracle AQ as a JMS in JBoss5

Tags: oracle, jms, message-driven-bean

I'm looking for a full example or detail tutorial how to set Oracle AQ as a JMSProvider. I would like to create MDB which would be executed by the messages from queue defined in Oracle AQ. I'm using JBoss AS 5.1 and Oracle 11

================

Thanks for the links. I've added Oracle AQ as a jms provider under my JBoss but i currently i have problem with enqueue message into queue. I got exception like this:

2011-10-07 09:18:02,938 INFO  [com.sun.genericjmsra:77] (http-10.243.0.66-8080-2) Unable to get managed connection for OracleXA
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: JMS-232: Podano niepoprawnego uĹźytkownika lub niepoprawne hasĹo dla poĹÄ

It means that I have an incorrect username or/and password. That data is 100% ok but maybe I put it in config file in a wrong way.

Here is part of my config:

```
<tx-connection-factory>
  <jndi-name>OracleXA</jndi-name>
  <rar-name>oracleaq.rar</rar-name>
  <connection-definition>javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory</connection-definition>
  <config-property name="ConnectionFactoryProperties" type="java.lang.String">host=IP_OF_MY_HOST,username=XXXX,password=YYYY,port=1521,sid=TESTAQ,driver=thin</config-property>
  <config-property name="username" type="java.lang.String">XXXX</config-property>
  <config-property name="password" type="java.lang.String">YYYY</config-property>
  <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
</tx-connection-factory>
```

I've built it based on example I found on some website. Is it necessary to put username and password twice? I've made some changes into this config but it didn't solve the problem :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it

instead of:

```
<config-property name="ConnectionFactoryProperties" type="java.lang.String">host=IP_OF_MY_HOST,username=XXXX,password=YYYY,port=1521,sid=TESTAQ,driver=thin</config-property>
```

the jdbc connection string can be used:

```
<config-property name="ConnectionFactoryProperties" type="java.lang.String">jdbc_connect_string=jdbc:oracle:thin:XXXX/YYYY@IP_OF_MY_HOST:1521/TESTAQ,host=IP_OF_MY_HOST,user=XXXX,password=YYYY,port=1521,sid=TESTAQ,driver=thin</config-property>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2011/10/creating-queue-in-oracleaq.html) will give you an idea on how to create queue melodramatically.
And [this one](http://biemond.blogspot.com/search/label/jms) give full idea on setting as JMS provider. (In this blog there are number of posts useful posts available)